# Prevent wget from creating nonexistent files from a wildcard download

Tags: bash, shell

I will download some files from a server via this shell script. If I download the files with this command `wget -Nc $url/$languages/$year/{1..53}$url_suffix -P $dir`, then likewise the calendar weeks > 43 are downloaded for the date 20/26/2023. Unfortunately `wget` does not abort the download by itself because the file does not exist on the server. It creates files with the calendar weeks 43 - 53. How do I solve the problem?

```
#!/bin/bash

# The URL is a combination of the languages, year and week of the year.
# Example URL https://example.com/greek/2020/29.gz
url=https://example.com
url_suffix=.gz

# List of intruments
greek=(Alpha Beta Gamma Delta)
german=(Auto Haus Boot)
english=(Hello)

# Year
year=(2019 2020 2021 2022 2023)

for languages in "${greek[@]}" "${german[@]}" "${english[@]}"; do
    for t in "${year[@]}"; do
        dir="ftp/$languages/$t"

        # Check if the directories exits
        if [[ ! -d $dir ]]; then
            mkdir -p $dir
        fi

        # Downlaod the files
        wget -Nc $url/$languages/$year/{1..53}$url_suffix -P $dir
    done
done
```

Comment: I can't replicate this. `wget -Nc https://www.google.com/nosuchpath.txt -P .` doesn't create anything. What is the content of the files created? Are you sure the server returns 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to break the script at the first `404` (Not found) you can do something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# The URL is a combination of the languages, year and week of the year.
# Example URL https://example.com/greek/2020/29.gz
url=https://example.com
url_suffix=.gz

# List of intruments
greek=(Alpha Beta Gamma Delta)
german=(Auto Haus Boot)
english=(Hello)

# Year
year=(2019 2020 2021 2022 2023)

for languages in "${greek[@]}" "${german[@]}" "${english[@]}"; do
    for t in "${year[@]}"; do
        dir="ftp/$languages/$t"
        mkdir -p $dir
        for week in "${url}/${languages}/${t}/"{1..53}"${url_suffix}"
        do
            wget -Nc $week -P $dir || break
        done
    done
done
```

Comment: If I use

`year=(2019 2020 2021 2022 2023)`

then the wget download files from 2019 Week 1 to Week 9. This is the content for the weeks 43 - 52 for the year 2023.

If I use 

`year=(2023)`

the script stopps in the correct week.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i wrote a not complete code just to give you a hint on how to resolve your problem. I've updated my answer with a more complete code, it should work for every year

Answer (score 2):

In `wget -Nc $url/$languages/$year/{1..53}$url_suffix -P $dir` you're probably only ever going to get 2019, as `$year` will always return the first element of the array. Use `$t`.

Will likely need some tweaking, but try letting `wget` grab them in one call.

```
url=example.com
url_suffix=.gz
greek=(Alpha Beta Gamma Delta)
german=(Auto Haus Boot)
english=(Hello)
year=(2019 2020 2021 2022 2023)
args=( --recursive --continue --timestamping --no-verbose --no-parent
       --accept="$url_suffix"
)
for languages in "${greek[@]}" "${german[@]}" "${english[@]}"; do
    for t in "${year[@]}"; do
        dir="ftp/$languages/$t"
        mkdir -p "$dir" # no need to test this first
        wget "${args[@]}" -P "$dir" "https://$url/$languages/$t/"
        mv "$dir/$url"/* "$dir/" && rm -fr "$dir/$url/"
    done
done
```

This should pull whatever is there so you won't need to specify `{1..53}` (which I think is your problem), but it creates a subfolder for the URL which you need to remove from your path. I added the `mv ... && rm ...` step for that. This is also why I removed `https://` from `$url` and added it explicitly.

Please test and tweak as needed, and good luck.